# variable value not incremented inside multiline IF statement in batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, command-prompt

I am using command prompt in windows 7.
I found this strange that variable value modified inside if clause is updated only after if clause has been completely executed.
Here is a simple example to show this.

```
@echo off
set /a somevar=0
set match_string="match"
:loop
echo at loop beginning - somevar is %somevar%
if %match_string% equ "match" (
set /a somevar+=1
echo somevar inside if statement after increment - %somevar%
)
echo somevar after if statement is %somevar%
pause
goto loop
```

How can I have updated somevar inside if statement ?

Thanks.

Comment: To  downvoter of this question - can you make que score as zero because i tried to explain my question and wrote a sample code to verify . i can delete the question but experts who have replied will be at loss . also , it can help someone in future . thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from a lack of `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set somevar=0
set "match_string=match"
:loop
echo before loop: %somevar%
if "%match_string%" == "match" (
     set /a somevar+=1
     echo inside loop: !somevar!
)
echo after loop: %somevar%
pause>nul
goto loop
```

Note `!somevar!` in the loop instead of `%somevar%`

You can read more on it by running `set /?` and `setlocal /?` from `cmd`

The reason however why I have not voted to close as duplicate is to also highlight your incorrect `if` statements and `set`ting of variables. See the changes I made in the answer.

I suppose it is also good to mention that in this particular case, you do not require the parenthesized block, and therefore not need `delayedexpansion` either.

```
@echo off
set somevar=0
set "match_string=match"
:loop
echo before loop: %somevar%
if "%match_string%" == "match" set /a somevar+=1
echo after if statement: %somevar%
pause>nul
goto loop
```

Comment: my question was intended to update variable inside if statement and use that updated value inside same if statement . so i posted an example in which if has multiple statement to execute . delayedexpansion looks useful for that . But i think you misunderstood when you wrote 'you do not require the parenthesized block, and therefore not need delayedexpansion'

Comment: Yes. And I answered your question exactly as requested. The second part was just an FYI. Use it, Don't use it.

Comment: ok . thanks . btw , i tried one thing which worked for my case . i added 'if "%match_string%" == "match" set /a somevar+=1' before multiline if to use updated value.

Comment: So now you have 2 `if` statements? For the same case? That is a little inefficient is it not? You have numerous options to implement, so if you are not keen on using `delayedexpansion` then use `call` to the actions block and then you can add as many options as you like without having to use `delayedexpansion`

Comment: i will use delayedexpansion . Out of curiosity, can you give link for alternative 'call' method ?

Comment: I will edit my answer and show you. Just give me some time as I am on my phone and not at home.

Comment: ok . no problem , i will wait .